# Index values from a matrix using row, col indices

Tags: r, indexing, matrix, r-faq

I have a 2D matrix `mat` with 500 rows × 335 columns, and a data.frame `dat` with 120425 rows. The data.frame `dat` has two columns `I` and `J`, which are integers to index the row, column from `mat`. I would like to add the values from `mat` to the rows of `dat`.

Here is my conceptual fail:

```
> dat$matval <- mat[dat$I, dat$J]
Error: cannot allocate vector of length 1617278737
```

(I am using R 2.13.1 on Win32). Digging a bit deeper, I see that I'm misusing matrix indexing, as it appears that I'm only getting a sub-matrix of `mat`, and not a single-dimension array of values as I expected, i.e.:

```
> str(mat[dat$I[1:100], dat$J[1:100]])
 int [1:100, 1:100] 20 1 1 1 20 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I was expecting something like `int [1:100] 20 1 1 1 20 1 1 1 1 1 ...`. What is the correct way to index a 2D matrix using indices of row, column to get the values?

Comment: +1 for an interesting question (which begs another question: why isn't there an option to change the behavior to something a little more like this when passing the `[` operator N vectors for an N-dimensional matrix?)

Comment: Nice question - I edited it very slightly to fix what I *think* is a typo (`datI` to `dat$I`). If this isn't what you meant feel free to undo...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Almost. Needs to be offered to "[" as a two column matrix:

```
dat$matval <- mat[ cbind(dat$I, dat$J) ] # should do it.
```

There is a caveat: Although this also works for dataframes, they are first coerced to matrix-class and if any are non-numeric, the entire matrix becomes the "lowest denominator" class.

Comment: +1 for finding the way that R clearly intended to do things ;-)

Comment: So if `I` and `J` are the only columns, is just `mat[dat]` sufficient? Or do you need to coerce to a matrix?

Comment: Seems coercion is necessary since the data frame is really a list. So you could also do `as.matrix(dat)`.

Comment: @gsk3: Look at the Arguments section for ?"[" under "..." . When an array or matrix is being addressed, the matrix must have the same number of columns as the addressed object has dimensions. There are also some examples on that help page.

Comment: What happens if the data.frame contains index values for I and J that are outside the bounds of the matrix? I'm pretty sure it will fail...I think @Tommy's answer will return NAs for that scenario. Just something to keep in mind...

Comment: This indexing method is rather obscure, not covered in "Intro to R" tutorials. I got curious and read the docs, [which does cover it](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Index-matrices)

Answer (score 11):

Using a matrix to index as DWin suggests is of course much cleaner, but for some strange reason doing it manually using 1-D indices is actually slightly faster:

```
# Huge sample data
mat <- matrix(sin(1:1e7), ncol=1000)
dat <- data.frame(I=sample.int(nrow(mat), 1e7, rep=T), 
                  J=sample.int(ncol(mat), 1e7, rep=T))

system.time( x <- mat[cbind(dat$I, dat$J)] )     # 0.51 seconds
system.time( mat[dat$I + (dat$J-1L)*nrow(mat)] ) # 0.44 seconds
```

The `dat$I + (dat$J-1L)*nrow(m)` part turns the 2-D indices into 1-D ones. The `1L` is the way to specify an integer instead of a double value. This avoids some coercions.

...I also tried gsk3's apply-based solution. It's almost 500x slower though:

```
system.time( apply( dat, 1, function(x,mat) mat[ x[1], x[2] ], mat=mat ) ) # 212
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner using `apply`'s row-based operations

```
> dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(seq(4),4),ncol=2))
> colnames(dat) <- c('I','J')
> dat
   I  J
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  3  3
4  4  4
5  1  1
6  2  2
7  3  3
8  4  4
> mat <- matrix(seq(16),ncol=4)
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    9   13
[2,]    2    6   10   14
[3,]    3    7   11   15
[4,]    4    8   12   16

> dat$K <- apply( dat, 1, function(x,mat) mat[ x[1], x[2] ], mat=mat )
> dat
  I J  K
1 1 1  1
2 2 2  6
3 3 3 11
4 4 4 16
5 1 1  1
6 2 2  6
7 3 3 11
8 4 4 16
```

Answer (score -1):

```
n <- 10
mat <- cor(matrix(rnorm(n*n),n,n))
ix <- matrix(NA,n*(n-1)/2,2)
k<-0
for (i in 1:(n-1)){
    for (j in (i+1):n){
    k <- k+1
    ix[k,1]<-i
    ix[k,2]<-j
    }
}
o <- rep(NA,nrow(ix))
o <- mat[ix]
out <- cbind(ix,o)
```

Comment: Some comments would be nice and make the answer be more "attractive".

Comment: You can not answer only a bunch of code... Come on... explain a little bit your answer :)