# Adding counts in matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector

my issue is that within a loop for every i - a matrix like this outputted

```
structure(c(8L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 28L, 32L, 24L, 32L, 8L, 64L, 
0L, 6L, 12L, 16L, 4L, 32L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 12L, 3L, 24L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 6L, 4L, 32L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
28L), .Dim = 6:7, .Dimnames = structure(list(c("ESN", "GWD", 
"LWK", "MSL", "PEL", "YRI"), c("ACB", "ESN", "GWD", "LWK", "MSL", 
"PEL", "YRI")), .Names = c("", "")), class = "table")
```

this matrix counts pariwise sharing - these counts should now be added to a larger table - with more levels than only the 7 present in this table. It is always a symmetric matrix (so the upper triangl) can be neglected

the real table (for which all elements are 0 in the beginnign)

```
matr<-matrix(0,nrow=26,ncol=26)
pop<-c("CHB","JPT","CHS","CDX","KHV","CEU","TSI","FIN","GBR","IBS","YRI","LWK","GWD","MSL","ESN","ASW","ACB","MXL","PUR","CLM","PEL","GIH","PJL","BEB","STU","ITU")

rownames(matr)<-pop
colnames(matr)<-pop
```

Can somebody tell me how I can add these counts from the small table to the large table (in the correct field) in an efficient way? I need to update the table 100k time - so effectiveness would be good. As mentioned addiing in the lower triangle is fine....

EDI #####

so another data set - might look like (this would then be generated from the next iteration of the loop)

```
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), .Dim = c(3L, 
3L), .Dimnames = structure(list(c("IBS", "MXL", "TSI"), c("GBR", 
"IBS", "MXL")), .Names = c("", "")), class = "table")
```

this should then also be added to matr - if a field has a number in it previously, the two number should be added up

Thanks

Comment: You'll need [matrix-indexing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920441/index-values-from-a-matrix-using-row-col-indicies) while assigning; i.e. in each step (having created a table "tab") you'll want to update the `cbind(rownames(tab)[row(tab)], colnames(tab)[col(tab)])` indices of "matr" by adding "tab".

Comment: @alexi_laz - but how to only add to the lower diagonal ? So if a count is added above the diagonal - it has to be (moved) below the diagonal ....

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it seems that -after updating with all "tab"s-, something like `matr + t(matr)` will update the lower triangle? And, then, add 0s to `upper.tri`

Comment: @alexis_laz apologies - not sure I understand would you mind laying out in a bit more detail, please like in answer that I could accept - why would you t() it?

Comment: Both of the "table"s in your example are not symmetric and, also, have duplicate entries with different values -- e.g.in the first table `["ESN", "GWD"] != ["GWD", "ESN"]` and in second `["IBS", "MXL"] != ["MXL", "IBS"]`. In the duplicate entries, will there -always- be one `== 0` and one `!= 0` or could both be `!= 0` and in "matr" their sum should be added? And are your "table"s, indeed, non-symmetric?

Comment: @alex_laz m1 is not symmetric yes - matr is symmetric. The dupl entries with different values would need to be added together - both could be different from 0,. Yes in matr the sum should be added - but under the diagonal - so the sum of both should be entered in the lower tri of the matrix...

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account duplicate/non-equal/non-zero entries in each of "table" created through iterations and updating only the `lower.tri` of "matr":

```
for(tab in tabs) {
     ## if each 'tab' is large enough, 
     ## instead of creating (and subsetting with) 'row(tab)' and 'col(tab)'
     ##, a 'rep(, each = )' could be used
     i = match(rownames(tab), rownames(mat))[row(tab)]
     j = match(colnames(tab), colnames(mat))[col(tab)]

     ## to fill only the 'lower.tri'
     ii = pmax(i, j); jj = pmin(i, j)

     ## sum duplicate entries 'tab' with 'sparseMatrix's intrinsic 'xtabs'-like behaviour
     ijx = summary(sparseMatrix(ii, jj, x = c(tab)))

     ## subset and assign with a matrix index updating previous entries
     ij = cbind(ijx$i, ijx$j)
     mat[ij] = mat[ij] + ijx$x
}
mat
#  a  b c d e
#a 0  0 0 0 0
#b 4  1 0 0 0
#c 6  7 2 0 0
#d 5 12 5 7 0
#e 4  6 3 3 0
```

where "tabs" is a "list" containing the -iteratively- created "table"s:

```
set.seed(007)            
tabs = replicate(3, table(replicate(2, 
                                    sample(letters[1:5], 50, TRUE), simplify = FALSE))[
                                        sample(5, sample(2:5, 1)), sample(5, sample(2:5, 1))], 
                 simplify = FALSE)
```

and "mat" is a smaller "matr":

```
mat = matrix(0L, 5, 5, dimnames = replicate(2, letters[1:5], simplify = FALSE))
```

Comment: but what is mat - how is it from mat?

Comment: @kutyw : I used the above "mat" and "tabs" as a more simple/extensive example; replacing "mat" with your "matr" and "tabs" with a "list" of the two "table"s `dput` included in your question and running the above, should result in the wanted/updated "matr"